# can you decalare a json array in uppaal?

Tags: uppaal

I am trying to model an ATM system in uppaal and I want to use a json array like a database for card_IDs and pin numbers like this :
  [ {
      id : 12548,
      pin: 1244 
  }]
is this possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JSON syntax is not supported. But it is possible to initialize in bulk, e.g.:

```
typedef struct { int id, pin; } id_pin_t;
id_pin_t array[3] = {{1,2}, {3,4},{5,6}};
```